# is there a way of modifying values loaded via CursorLoader and just before displaying to the textview

Tags: android, android-listview, loader

I'm using plain old ListViews, SimpleCursorAdapter, LoaderCallback etc. to read values from a database and display in textViews.

sample code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cateory_list);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.category_parent,
            null,
            new String[] {CategoryTable.COL_2},
            new int[] {R.id.text_view},
            0);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("content")
            .appendPath(CategoryTable.TB_NAME)
            .authority("com.example.auth")
            .build();

    return new CursorLoader(this, uri, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Everything works well and the values from database are displayed on the listview. But suppose I want to do some text processing of the values before displaying, how can I do that?

Edit 1: I don't want to do the text processing in main-thread. Is there a way I can use the AsynTaskLoader thread created from CursorLoader and off-load the work over there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create a Custom Loader by extending CursorLoader and only overriding `public Cursor loadInBackground()`

This way I'm retrieving the data, do long running text processing, insert the result back to new table and return the cursor of the new table.

Sample code:

```
@Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Cursor cursor = super.loadInBackground();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        try {
            ActiveAndroid.beginTransaction();
            do {
                String s = doProcessing(cursor.getString(colNumber));
                createAndInsertIntoNewTable(s);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            ActiveAndroid.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            ActiveAndroid.endTransaction();
        }

        return cursorFromNewTable;
    }
```

This completely does the work in AsyncTaskLoader thread and solves my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  It is called a `ViewBinder`. You want a `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`, in your case.  It is called just as the data is moved from the adapter, in to the view.

Be careful, though.  It is called a *lot* (likely several times for each view in each cell of the list).  It needs to run really fast and, unless you want to drive the GC nuts, should not allocate anything.

Comment: actually my text processing can take time. Is there a way to offload the work on the same AsyncTaskLoader thread somehow

Comment: Sure.  Do the processing on some asynchronous thread and store the result in the DB.  You cannot do expensive stuff in a View Binder.

Comment: I already have the values in DB, and I'm retrieving them from CursorLoader right, Now while reading the values here itself I want to do some text processing (I assume cursorLoader is already doing in some thread). In my scenraio the text processing is not one time thing. I want to do for every read from database.

Comment: Perhaps I am not being clear.  You *can* modify stuff, as it goes from the cursor to the view.  Use a SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.  You *cannot* do anything expensive (complex text processing) in the ViewBinder.  If you need to do anything expensive, precompute it, store it in the DB, and use the Loader/Adapter to put it in a view.

Comment: then you can use w CursorWrapper and do your long task in the worker thread followed by requery() or onChange() call

Comment: I *really* suggest not.  Store your intermediate values in the DB!  What happens if your app is halfway through doing the text manipulation, when it gets stopped?!  Throw the work away?